# QTableView does not display database in release mode

Tags: c++, dll, exe, release-management, qsqltablemodel

I have written an application in `C++` using `Qt 4.8` in `Visual Studio 2010` and I try to make `.exe` with `dll`s. Everything seems to work just fine, but

when  **I run my program on another computer without any VS or Qt installed there, nothing gets displayed.**

//class where I create database

```
DatabaseManager::DatabaseManager():
        m_database(new QSqlDatabase(QSqlDatabase::addDatabase("QSQLITE")))
   {   
         m_database->setDatabaseName("VirtualBank.db");
        m_database->setHostName("localhost");
   }
```

// Widget that has holds QTableView where that database gets displayed

```
CorporationWidget
    {
  //....
        QTableView * m_wgt;
            QSqlRelationalTableModel* m_model;
  //....
    }

 void CorporationWidget::initializeModel()
{
    setModel(new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this,*(getContext()->model->getDatabase())));
  //....
}
```

Normal view: (on my computer)
[image]

Not normal view (on someone else's computer)
[image]

The `dll`s in folder:
[image]

Comment: You should not have or need the *90.dll files in your Release folder. If you need them then there is a real problem with your libraries because you are using 2 different CRTs and 2 independent heaps each compiler version (in this case VS2008 and VS2010) has its own heap and runtime. Having this situation can lead to crashes and UB.

Comment: I can delete them - the problem still occurs